# Create a button on click of a button

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a button and I need to create more buttons when I pressed the button.

Here it is what I have written for the button:

```
<div class="response-container" id="response-container">
    <a href="#" class="button add-button" id="add-button">Add button</a>
</div>
```

I am trying to learn Backbone.js so I wrote a view to create more buttons when click add-button.

```
createButton = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .add-button': 'add_script'
    },
    add_script: function() {
        console.log('Pressed');
        //create a new button from here? 
     }
});
```

Can anyone help me to do it? `console.log('Pressed')` doesn't even work. I am trying to learn web development so, is there any document that you can suggest me? I am welcome for all suggestions in Backbone.js

Comment: Could you please either clean up your HTML or post the whole thing? I'm unsure what's going there

Comment: It is supposed to be like this.......   events: {
    "click .add-button" : "add_script"
},

Comment: explain us what does this mean [  'click .add-script-button': 'add_script' ] in your code @waterkinq

Comment: As I said I am new in Backbone.js. I just look at the examples of it and for all examples, they determine some events so for this, it means when the button whose id is add-script-button clicked, do what I have written in the add_Script function. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object of the view.
Like this

```
var createButton = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#response-container',
    events: {
        'click .add-button': 'add_script'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log("initialized");
    },
    add_script: function() {
        console.log('Pressed');
        //create a new button from here? 

    this.$el.append('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');


     }
});
```

`var cb = new createButton();`

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zijevuvepo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: That's it thank you I did not know initialize function is necessary. Thank you it works

Comment: It is not necessary I put it for you to understand that when we create the object of the view via new, the view's initialize method is called.

Answer (score 1):

How your are trying to achieve this is not best practice (because this should be done through template) but you can do this:
fist you must define el element example in your case el: '#response-container'

```
events: {
        'click #add-button': 'add_script'
    },
    add_script: function() {
        console.log('Pressed');
        //if you have el 
        this.$el.append('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
        //or as jquyer add element  
         var r= $('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
            $("body").append(r);
     }
```

Comment: I really dont understand how can he make script work when his event is wrong ie., instead of using the class .add-button, he is trying to call for .add-script-button, Am i wrong?